# How to check if the "?" of a Class<?> object instanceof SomeInterface

Tags: java, generics, reflection, instanceof

Simple-*looking*-problem, but I'm starting to think I'm trying to achieve something the wrong way. Let's say I have a `Method` object correctly initialized.

I need to check if that method will return an object implementing the `Comparable` interface.

The problem is `method.getReturnType()` returns a `Class<?>` object, I want to check if this "?" actually is an instance of Comparable, but I can't write `? instanceof Comparable`, how would anyone do that?

EDIT: I know I could do `result = method.invoke(someObject)` and then `result instanceof Comparable` but I need to do these kind of checks in the constructor of my bigger object, dunno if I'm clear.

Comment: If a method returns, for example, a String, then the Class returned by Method.getReturnType is String.class. So you need to test if String.class has Comparable in its ancestors, i.e. is Comparable.class is assignable from String.class (hint hint).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Comparable.class.isAssignableFrom(method.getReturnType())
```